# Jquery promises in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am trying to call a function 3 times which injects some mark-up provided by an ad network to my articles. I am trying to implement with promises and a for loop as follows:

```
var targetParagraph = x;
var slots = {
     8 : '<div>some content</div>',
     9 : '<div>some content</div>',
     10 : '<div>some content</div>'
};

 Object.keys(slots).forEach(function(key) {
      let scriptMarkup = '<div id="snack_dex' + key + '"></div>' + slots[key];
      injectArticleContent(targetParagraph, scriptMarkup).done(function() {
           console.log('done!');
      });
 });

 function injectArticleContent(targetParagraph, scriptMarkup){
      return $( ".js-article-body p:nth-child(" + targetParagraph + ")").after(scriptMarkup);
 }
```

When I run the above I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: injectArticleContent(...).done is not a function

Why is injectArticleContent not a function? I have been looking at past solutions for ours but just cannot figure this out, any ideas?

Comment: The `injectArticleContent` function doesn't return something which has a `done` method.

Comment: There are no promises in the example and none of your code is asynchronous. Why do you feel you need `done()` here at all?

Comment: `Why is injectArticleContent not a function?` The error is saying that `done()` isn't a function on the response from the `injectArticleContent` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that getting markup is an async task, you can create a list of promises an resolve them with Promise.all()

```js
let getMarkup = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve("markup from server")
  }, 1000)
})

var targetParagraph = 'x';
var slots = {
  8: '<div>some content</div>',
  9: '<div>some content</div>',
  10: '<div>some content</div>'
};

let promisses = Object.keys(slots)
  .map(k => getMarkup(k).then(res => injectArticleContent(k, res)))

Promise.all(promisses)

function injectArticleContent(targetParagraph, scriptMarkup) {
  console.log('rendering new post:: ', targetParagraph, scriptMarkup)
  return $(".js-article-body p:nth-child(" + targetParagraph + ")").after(scriptMarkup);
}
```